# For searching questions there should be option for "asked today" or "unmodified questions"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For searching unanswered questions it shows questions modified x mins ago. To see unmodified questions or to see questions which are asked just today, there should be option to select "Questions asked today" or "unmodified questions".

I see we can search by a searchstring "created:2014-04-20 is:q" to see asked questions today.

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2014-04-20+is%3Aq
```

but in website if there is a button for this then it would be good I think.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Today, yesterday, last week, fortnight, month, quarter, year, ... Hmm..